# Operator overloading not yet supported?

Tags: operator-overloading, swift

According to the Swift Programming Guide, operator overloading is allowed and actually quite versatile. However, I have been unable to get it working in the playground.

For example, the `Equatable` protocol wants this: `func ==(lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Bool`

Let's say I make a simple `Location3D` struct:

```
struct Location3D
{
    var x : Double
    var y : Double
    var z : Double
}
```

Now I want this `Location3D` to implement the `Equatable` protocol, so I add it along with this method:

```
func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x &&
           lhs.y == rhs.y &&
           lhs.z == rhs.z
}
```

I get the compiler error of **operators are only allowed at global scope**. Huh?

So I tried adding `@infix` to the function, moving the function to an extension, changing the type to a class instead... all to no avail.

Am I missing something? How are you supposed to implement `Equtable` and `Comparable` when operators don't seem to work?

Comment: `global scope` would point to a location outside of any Class or extension declaration

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to override the == operator in the global scope but with your type for the arguments.

In this case it means you declare your struct to conform to the protocol and then simply implement the function outside it's scope.

```
struct Location3D : Equatable {
    // ...
}

func ==(lhs: Location3D, rhs: Location3D) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```

See the library reference for further discussion:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: I wonder why Apple would make it so unintuitive. If you are overloading an operator for a given class, why impose this restriction? It makes sense to have the operator `func` defined **inside** the class definition, like the other methods.

Comment: Note that if the `struct` is within a class, the operator overload has to go outside of the scope of the class as well (truly global scope).

Comment: `==`  is infix operator, When overriding we don't need to specify it, right ?